# In GeoGebra applet line and circle tools work wrong

Tags: applet, geogebra

I prepared an applet embedded in a HTML page. When I choose a line tool for example and make click on the GeoGebra area then it is supposed that the first point  should be drawn and after
the second click the second point and entire line should be drawn. But instead of that I immediately get a line with 2 points. The same thing with circle tool: after first click that means place of the center I get entire circle with some radius. How this problem could be solved?

Comment: You need to include all your html code

Comment: I believe this is a "feature" of GeoGebra: it's previewing what the line or circle will look like if you make the second click. I don't know if there's a way to turn this preview off.